# GDB in Qt Creator : common condition to all breakpoints to only break on a given data-step

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, qt-creator

I am working on and with a C & C++ app that is heavily step-based. In fact what it does is replay step-based recordings of some data and apply some processing on the data of every data-step. It can pause on every data-step and show you what it did in details. The app also offers to rewind to a previous step (which basically starts the replay from data-step 0 and runs up to data-step n-1).

When I see something weird in a data-step and want to debug, I only want to hit my breakpoints (under their respective conditions) if I am in data-step number n, say. Then, if I `continue` and rewind to data-step n-1, I want no hits, even if the same piece of code is executed at some of the other steps from 0 to n-1. This would allow me to quickly rewind to n-1 (i.e. replay from the start up to data-step n-1) then play data-step n again and debug some other branch of the code which I had previously jumped over.

I have access to a variable giving me the current step and so I can use it in a break condition and thus create conditional breakpoints, but this is clumsy as I end up having to do this every time I create a breakpoint (and often have to add this to another condition that I already want for this break point i.e. `<condition> && (step == n)` - which is double-clumsy, especially with the minuscule text field that Qt Creator offers for that).

Is this possible using GDB and Qt Creator ? I know you can step up a breakpoint to enable or disable all the others upon being hit (call them control breakpoints), but then these control breakpoints also disable themselves and this only works once. You can then specify that when disabling all breakpoints as part of the action of the control breakpoints, you do still enable these control breakpoints. But for this you need an ID, and it seems to change overtime, if not at every disable/enable, at least at every debug session. Any other idea ?

Comment: Not sure about Qt Creator, but in GDB I would create a [convenience variable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html), like `set $step=n`, and use it in the breakpoint conditions, like `(step == $step)`, or maybe even `($step < 0 || step == $step)`, then I could easily change which step the breakpoints will stop in.

Comment: 1. I have access to a variable already in my program that gives me the step.
2. I want to avoid writing this extra condition in all my breakpoints.